# What does the expression of 'mountain frowning on me' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, expressions

I have stumbled upon this expression twice now, once in Bram Stoker's Dracula in which he writes:

> Then the mountains seemed to come nearer to us on each side and to frown down upon us.

and in The Hobbit which writes:

> The river goes on and on and the mountain in the distance seems to frown down on him.

What is it about a mountain that makes it frown, and is there a symbolic meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing in the definition of either that connects mountains to frowns, nor is it a common idiom. It is probably used in these specific cases for literary effect. I think it's an allusion to how one would feel in front of a large, powerful, frowning authority figure. It's intended to be a little bit intimidating or ominous.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the shape of the eye brows

[image]

you can see the lines like two mountain curves.

This picture from [Pentaxuser](https://www.pentaxuser.com/photo/frowning-mountains-5669/large) is called "frowning mountains":

[image]

You can see the same shape like frowning eyebrows which I have indicated with red lines.

I have found the phrase "frown on/upon" explained as

> disapprove of, dislike, discourage, take a dim view of, look askance
> at, discountenance, view with disfavour, not take kindly to, show
> disapproval or displeasure ([Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Frowned+Upon#:%7E:text=frown%20on%20or%20upon%20something,frowned%20upon%20as%20being%20wasteful.))

***Frown down*** is more difficult to find. In the description of ***frown***, I have found this:

> To look or act disapprovingly or threateningly; lower: as, to frown
> upon a scheme. To repress or repel by an aspect of displeasure; rebuke
> by a stern or angry look or by severe words or conduct: as, to frown
> one into silence; ***to frown down a proposition***. ([Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/frown#:%7E:text=To%20repress%20or%20repel%20by,to%20frown%20down%20a%20proposition.&text=noun%20Any%20expression%20or%20show,as%2C%20the%20frowns%20of%20Providence.))

Now a mountain is tall and looks like frowning (that's why it is said to ***frown down***). Depending on the context, it can mean either ***intimidating*** or ***threatening***, ***hostile***.

Comment: Is that a sweatdrop above the eyebrow? [Emanata](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/emanata) much? :P

Comment: Note that speakers of British English see a frown as an arrangement of the brows, whereas American English generally uses it to refer to the mouth. See the [''Separated by a Common Language'' blog](https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2016/09/frowns.html)

Comment: @EddieKal: Funny :) I thought of editing the picture, but allowed myself to be lazy in the end. Which I don't regret, because it gave you the opportunity to teach me a new word, like Emanata! Thanks!

Comment: @ColinFine: Thank you very much for your input. As a non-native, there was no way I would know this!

Comment: I was going to comment before asking what this has to do with a frown, then I saw @ColinFine's input.

Answer (score 1):

Sir Arthur Conan Doyle talks about 'staring villas" which resemble human faces with large rectangular eyes which seem to 'stare' at the viewer.

[image]